# HRIR and DT Convolution

Tags: filters, convolution, finite-impulse-response

You have an experimentally-measured HRIR and an audio signal. And you wish to implement filtering using scientific libraries in Python such as numpy, scipy and matplotlib(for plotting)

Question A) In order to implement an FIR causal filter using a time domain convolution which function from the SciPy library do you use?

Question B) and what are the steps/stages involved between getting the DT samples and filtering- list or flowchart this answer.
Will post codes and plots here after these instructions

shared details for now:

1. The audio signal/samples is coming from a Wav file (1-channel) with 20 sec (882000 samples -rate :44.1 kHz)
2. HRIR are MATLAB (.MAT) files from a public database.

Comment: i didn't vote to close, but this is solely a programming question with a DSP application.  some might say that this *"How to use Python SciPy and such?"* should go to Stack Overflow.